# Set width of element to "0" (not absolute positioned) with CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I have an element and even if i define "max-width=0" it has a width of 4px, see the image:

[image: i want to remove the gap on the upper left]

When i position the element absolute it is gone but due to the css transition (logo slides in on scroll down > 250px) i can not position it absolute.

This is the CSS:

```
#page-wrap.oben ul#menu li.menutext {
    padding: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#page-wrap.oben li.menutext a {
    font-size: 24px;
    max-width: 0;
    opacity: 0;        
    vertical-align: middle;

    -webkit-transition: all .6s;
    -moz-transition: all .6s;
    -ms-transition: all .6s;
    -o-transition: all .6s;
    transition: all .6s;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<li class="menutext biggerfont">
   <a href="#">
       Schooool!
   </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have a space between your `</li><li>` elements. If you remove the whitespace in between the closing and opening li this will eliminate the gap.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the way that `display: inline-block;` works, so you have the following options:

**Use float instead**

This will stack the elements directly next to each other.

```
ul#menu li {
    float: left;
}
```

**Set the text size of the `ul` to 0, then specify the height in the `li`**

This will mean that the gap left by `inline-block` does not take up any space, so the same effect

```
ul#menu {
    font-size: 0;
}
ul#menu li {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

**Change your HTML mark up**

The new line between `<li>` elements is the cause of this problem.  If you don't want to change the css then removing the line breaks between the closing and opening tags will have the same effect, and allow you to continue to use `inline-block`

`<li>item</li><li>
Item2</li><li>
Item3</li>`

None of this is tested on your example, but any of the solutions should work for you.  The `float` example might cause you different issues, depending on how your containers are set up.

Answer (score 0):

In the example, setting `li` in `float:left;` fix it, I don't know if it's what you are looking for.